# LLVM builder::GetInsertBlock, what's the purpose of this function?

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm trying to understand what do the following `IRBuilder` methods are used in LLVM for

```
BasicBlock *GetInsertBlock() const { return BB; }
BasicBlock::iterator GetInsertPoint() const { return InsertPt; }
```

There's no doxygen documentation for them. What happens if, for instance, I use for the first time `mybuilder.GetInsertBlock()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IRBuilder` has a "current insertion point" concept. For example, if you create a pair of instructions, it knows that the 2nd comes after the 1st. Where is that information maintained? In those `BB` and `InsertPt` fields, that point to the current basic block and instruction.

The pair of methods you mention provide direct access to these fields. I'm guessing it's not documented because accessing those directly is not the "proper" way to use an `IRBuilder`, but they are nonetheless useful.